# Slide inner div full height up and down inside outer div

Tags: jquery, css, html, jquery-animate

I hope I can describe this well enough, I apologize if it's a little long but I want to be descriptive. This is a simplified version of the problem I'm having on a site I'm currently working on:

I have an inner div inside an outer div- the height of the inner div is not static, sometimes it's height is 'x' pixels while another 'y'. The outer div is a fixed height with overflow:hidden for the overlap of the inner divs, in all cases the inner divs are larger in height than the outer.

My problem is I need to animate the inner div to slide up and down the full height of the inner div so that all of it shows within the outer div. You can see I tried using animate with a percentage here (33% was arbitrary):

http://jsfiddle.net/FLMp8/301/

```
var stuff = $('#inner1, #inner2');

function runIt() {
    stuff.animate({
        top: '-=33%'
    }, 3000);
    stuff.animate({
        top: '+=33%'
    }, 3000, runIt);
}

runIt();
```

I can't seem to get it to work uniformly no matter the height however. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
var stuff = $('#inner1, #inner2');

function runIt() {
    stuff.each(function() {
        $(this).animate({
            top: '0'
        }, 3000);
    });
    stuff.each(function() {
        $(this).animate({
            top: -$(this).height() + $(this).parent('div').height()
        }, 3000, runIt);
    });
}

runIt();
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/FLMp8/320/)

You can simplify this code as follows

```
var stuff = $('#inner1, #inner2');

function runIt() {
    stuff.each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.animate({
            top: '0'
        }, 3000).animate({
            top: -$this.height() + $this.parent('div').height()
        }, 3000, runIt);
    });
}

runIt();
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/FLMp8/327/)

Comment: That's closer! But I should have been more clear that their shouldn't be any space above or below the inner div and the outer div.

Comment: Quick question: how would you do it so that it starts at the top and only moves down and then stops. Basically how it starts out without the looping effect?

Comment: at last you are calling the function `runIt` ,that's why it's repeating

Comment: It was actually a different problem I was having (solved now) but thanks anyhow!